# Volume within the sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid that lies within the sphere [image],
 above the xy plane, and outside the cone [image]

My problem is finding the integral function and the limits

Comment: The integral function: $1,$ the limits are given by $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2},$ and $z=7\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Comment: well could you give me more explanation about the limits ?

Comment: Inside the sphere but outside the cone, so I guess it ought to look like this. No more than a comment. :D

Comment: well, I am still confused! could you please help me to get it

Comment: Sorry, if I thought I could explain better, I would post an answer. Hope someone better than me in this area could post. In any case, thanks for responding. :)

Comment: This is a polar problem.  You're going to have a tough time if you attack it using Cartesian coordinates.  Sure, you could technically do it, then transform to either cylindrical or spherical coordinates, but it's going to be easier to just start thinking in one of those coordinates (I'm not sure which, cylindrical or spherical, makes more sense).  I would build it up like a washer--the cone cuts a hole in the washer at each value of z (which I think suggests cylindrical coordinates makes the most sense).

Comment: could you help to do it because I feel that i am getting closer but still did not get the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here is a [sketch](http://sketchtoy.com/59889155) showing that the cone cuts out washers at each value of $z$.  The inner radius is given by the cone and the outer radius by the sphere.  In cylindrical coordinates, the cone is given by $z = 7r$ and the sphere by $r^2 + z^2 = 1 \rightarrow r^2 = 1 - z^2$.  The $z$ coordinate goes from $z = 0$ to whatever value of $z$ makes the radius of the cone equal to the radius of the sphere (at that $z$ value):

$$
\text{cone}: r = \frac{z}{7} \text{ plug into sphere equation}\\
\left(\frac{z}{7}\right)^2 + z^2 = 1 \rightarrow z^2 = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{49}} = \frac{49}{50} \\
z_{top} = \frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}
$$

Now you just need to find the volume of each differential washer:

$$
dV = Adh = \pi(R^2 - r^2)dz = \pi\left((1 - z^2) - \left(\frac{z}{7}\right)^2\right)dz
$$

The outer radius, $R$, is from the sphere and the inner radius, $r$, is from the cone.  So finally, you get the volume:

$$
V = \int dV = \pi\int\limits_0^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}}\left(1 - \frac{50}{49}z^2\right)dz = \pi\left.\left(z - \frac{50}{147}z^3\right)\right|_0^{\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}} \\
V = \pi \left(\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} - \frac{50}{3\cdot49}\cdot\frac{7^3}{50\sqrt{50}}\right) \\
V = \pi\left(\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}} - \frac{7}{3\sqrt{50}}\right) = \frac{7\pi}{\sqrt{50}}\cdot \frac{2}{3} = \frac{14\pi}{3\sqrt{50}}
$$

**edit**

If you absolutely must, the "full" integral, in cylindrical coordinates, would be something like this:

$$
V = \int\limits_0^\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}}dz\int\limits_{\frac{z}{7}}^{\sqrt{1 - z^2}}dr\int\limits_0^{2\pi} rd\phi
$$

...but it's easier to visualize it in this case and just use high school geometry to create a single integral.

Comment: thank you i really appreciate your help